# Apache/PHP cache headers problem

Tags: php, apache, caching, header

```
<?php
    chdir('../../../../');
    include('bootstrap.php');

    $place = isset($_GET['place'])  ?   (is_array($_GET['place']))   ?   intval($_GET['place'][0]) :   intval($_GET['place'])      : null;

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `place`, `image`, `imagetype` FROM `topvideo` WHERE `place` = '" . $place . "'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query))
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $im = imagecreatefromstring($row['image']);
            if ($im !== false)
            {
                header('Cache-Control: public, proxy-revalidate');
                header('Last-Modified:Mon, 02 Nov 2009 09:50:18 GMT');
                header('Expires: ' . gmdate ("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 24 . ' GMT');

                header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
                imagejpeg($im);
                imagedestroy($im);
            }
        }
    }
```

The response is always  200, but I need to cache the image for 2 days and the response was 304.... why?
sorry for bad english

Comment: *"The answer is always 200"* Then what is the question? On a more serious note, isn't a [`2xx Success`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success) exactly what you'd expect? Do you use a tool to see the full headers?

Comment: @jensgram i want a 304 cached... i'm using a tamper data in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to send 304 You need to include Etag in your response headers, etag is something like hash of content itself and date of it's creation.

After you include etag in response the browser will send you request header "If-None-Match".

You have to compare this headers and if they match respond with 304, if not send new content with new Etag header and status 200.